# How to position text in the right size, typed vertically, in a box?

Tags: html, css, text, css-position

I'm trying to put some text vertically written, on the right side of a box. I've got the vertically part down, but I can't put it on the right side. How can I set the position of my text inside the box?

```css
.aboutbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  text-align: bottom;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutbox">ABOUT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider padding instead of setting width:

```css
.aboutbox {
  padding-right: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutbox">ABOUT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use another div for text:

CSS

```
.aboutbox {
    background-color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 6px solid black;
}
.abouttxt {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="aboutbox">
    <div class="abouttxt">
    ABOUT
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-align is not needed here , but transform is handy with scaling instead rotation:

```css
.aboutbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  }
  .right {
  transform:scale(-1,-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutbox right">ABOUT right</div>
<hr>
<div class="aboutbox">ABOUT</div>
```

You may also use sideways-rl and flex alignement

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode
>
> `sideways-rl`
>
> Content flows vertically from top to bottom and all the glyphs, even those in vertical scripts, are set sideways toward the right.

```css
.aboutbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}

@supports (writing-mode: sideways-lr) {
  .disclaimer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="aboutbox">ABOUT</div>
<p class="disclaimer">Your browser does not support <code>writing-mode: sideways-lr;</code>, forget it !</p>
```